# Looping though an array in java spliting the elements

Tags: java

So I have an array in java that looks like this:

```
int[] theArray = {2,3,6,9,10,12,17,16,18,20,23,24,28,30,31};
```

Desired output:

```
2  3  6  9  10
12 17 16 18 20
23 24 28 30 31
```

Comment: Hi dear my actual code contain at least 50 elements in the array. the looks like this: String[] theArray = primes.split(" ");

Comment: I'm basically spliting the String whenever theres an space to get all the elements, but my problem is that I dont know how to print out just the four elements and then go to the next line and then print out the next four elements and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i =0;i<theArray.length;i++)
{
if(i%5==0 && i!=0)
{System.out.println();
}
System.out.print(theArray[i]+" ");
}
```

Comment: `if(i%5==0 && i!=0)` to prevent newline at the beginning

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is go through the array one by one, and use `System.out.print` to print the elements for each set of 5 elements. Once you have printed 5 elements, do a `system.out.println("");`

Comment: But my actual array has about 50 elements and if I go through the entire array it will take me a lot of time. Is there a way to loop the array?

Comment: yes that's what i meant by go through the array one by one (loop). you can use a for loop or a while loop

Comment: I know I have to use a for loop or while loop but how to implement the code inside the for loop?

Answer (score 1):

So, basically you want to output the values in an array with a newline after every fifth element? You can use the [modulo operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) to achieve that.

In (untested) code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayWithNumbers.length; i++)
{
    if (i % 5 == 0 && i != 0) // end of the line
    {
        System.out.println(arrayWithNumbers[i]);
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print(arrayWithNumbers[i]);
    }
}
```